# converting an automated voice recording into text using python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, wave

**Use case**: I have put my phone on speaker, dialled customer care ,recorded automated voice message on my laptop , now I want convert that into text.

**What I did until now ?**

I tried with speech recognition library in python

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import time 
r=sr.Recognizer()

#This block will help in recognising audio file harvard = sr.AudioFile('voice1.wav') with harvard as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.record(source,offset=0, duration=5)

print r.recognize_google(audio, show_all=True)
```

However, no text is returned.

Comment: as far as i know google speech API is blocked, try sphinx may be!!

Comment: sphinx producing random text

Comment: yeah, sphinx accuracy is bad, there are some methods to improve sphinx accuracy using dictionaries etc.

Comment: @raviraja can you share some example or link

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.
I created a virtual assistant using the google speech API. It turns out the **main problem** is with the **microphone** threshold. Try playing with its **threshold.** Because when you record a stream in real-time try saving it and listening to it locally. 
There is a parameter in microphone function which is a threshold, try changing that because by default tunning its pretty bad if the microphone is builtin.

The Google speech API might be block (but its working for me even though I am not using any token).
Although the preferred option is to use Tokens in Google API (speech to text)
While the text is returned in a perfect form.
Check the documentation of speech recognition. There are tons of other APIs as well.